# Why would the editor of a reputable journal act simultaneously as the editor of a potentially predatory journal?

Tags: editors, disreputable-publishers

Can anybody explain why someone who is editor of a reputable journal also act simultaneously as an editor for a potentially predatory journal?

Comment: Voting to close because Arun Bansil is likely the only person who can really answer this.

Comment: I’ve edited the question to focus on the central issue. Calling out an individual editor in such a manner is inflammatory.

Answer (score 7):

We cannot know if this is really the case, but many disreputable publishers surreptitiously list well known scientists in their editorial boards, without asking their consent.

Answer (score 3):

The editor is the only person that knows for sure. Some possibilities (note I do not know if ikpress is a flaky publisher - I'm simply assuming it is):

- He doesn't think ikpress is a flaky publisher. Compare Frontiers and MDPI, both publishers that were included on Beall's list that also had established academics defending them.
- He isn't aware ikpress is a flaky publisher.
- He doesn't care that ikpress is a flaky publisher (for whatever reason).
- He doesn't know he's listed as an editor, or he might have tried to be "unlisted" but the publisher has been slow at removing him.

Comment: Why you do not enter into the key issue? that is, what is reputation?

Comment: I don't see how reputation is relevant?